# Connect my computer with Ethernet Hardwire

Tags: ethernet

Does anyone know how and if I can hardwire my computer with Ethernet if I have Wi-Fi?  I got hired for a home based job and they require my computer to have Ethernet hardwire connection but I can't give up my wifi... If so, how do I do it?

Comment: Do you have a desk you can work at which is fairly close to the router? If so, you can use an Ethernet cable to connect your computer and the router. (Ethernet cable = [Cat 5e cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable).)

Comment: Unfortunately no ... My home office is upstairs and the router is downstairs. Right now my computer is connected to a modem...is there a simple solution?

Comment: You appear to have a route for wiring so use that

Comment: Sorry for the complete ignorance... But could you walk me through that?

Comment: @NeverGiveUp It is a fairly simple thing to do usually, but it does depend on the layout of your home. A Google search for "how to connect ethernet from downstairs to upstairs" will give you plenty of material to study.

Answer (score 1):

Cable (Ethernet) connection is preferred thanks to being more predictable/reliable than wireless, and perhaps more secure. Some newer devices especially laptops or tablets do not have a direct Ethernet port for connecting via cable, expecting that user will use only wireless connectivity. If for some reason the cable connectivity is required it is usually being achieved by a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, creating a new Ethernet card connected to the computer via a regular USB port. Cable can then go from there to the router/switch/AP.

For devices with USB-C there are several USB-C adapters either for single-purpose (such as the Ethernet) or for multiple purposes in one device, such as offering a HDMI monitor output, multiple USB 3.0 (A) ports and also a Gigabit Ethernet port for connecting via cable. Drivers should usually install automatically on all modern OSs (OSX, Win10, Linux).
Then usually just connecting the Ethernet port to the port of the router/switch with a UTP Cat5e/Cat6 cable should be enough to get network/internet connectivity.

Some laptops automatically disable WiFi if cable connection is detected (but in BIOS or software it can be changed), some allow both connections at once (with the cable one usually having a higher priority).

Answer (score 0):

Your computer will have one of:
RJ45 Ethernet connection
Port for Ethernet dongle (I have this)
USB port that you can use for an Ethernet connection.

You can use one of these to connect your Ethernet connection.

Wireless is TCP/IP as is Ethernet but they are entirely different physical media.

I assume your router provides an Ethernet port as most do